# Do these sentences need commas?

Tags: commas

Below are some examples of sentences that I have seen written both ways in professional material. The latter two cases were written by C.S. Lewis in That Hideous Strength (his versions are the sentences without the commas). Lewis seems to omit commas in cases where style guides might recommend them. Which of the two versions for each of these five sentences is correct?

> *If you send the letter tomorrow, that will be fine.
>
> If you send the letter tomorrow that will be fine.*

> *If they are drinking water, they will be okay.
>
> If they are drinking water they will be okay.*

> *Every month or so over the past few years, Jim sends me an email reminder to check the vendor website.
>
> Every month or so over the past few years Jim sends me an email reminder to check the vendor website.*

> *To a little midland market town like Edgestow, even visitors from the side of the county had hitherto ranked as aliens.
>
> To a little midland market town like Edgestow even visitors from the side of the county had hitherto ranked as aliens.* (Lewis)

> *I know it sounds silly, but in a way I felt sorry for it because it had no hands and couldn't wipe its mouth.
>
> I know it sounds silly but in a way I felt sorry for it because it had no hands and couldn't wipe its mouth.* (Lewis)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142958/discussion-on-question-by-grammarguy-do-these-sentences-need-commas); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/614851/2085).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from formal usages of the comma, listed for example in the Cambridge material below, one of the functions of punctuation is to give some information relating to speech patterns, as the Cambridge quote also makes clear.

Therefore, consider how you might say these sentences. Without the pause or change of tone implied by the comma, they may be more difficult for the hearer to understand. The pause implied by the comma allows the hearer to recognise the first thought, before it is related to the second thought.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/punctuation)
> In speaking, we use pauses and the pitch of the voice to make what we say clear. Punctuation plays a similar role in writing, making it easier to read.
>
> Punctuation consists of both rules and conventions. There are rules of punctuation that have to be followed; but there are also punctuation conventions that give writers greater choice.
> …
> Separating clauses with commas
>
> When main clauses are separated by and, or, but, we don’t normally use a comma if the clauses have the same subject. However, we sometimes use commas if the clauses have different subjects:
>
> They were very friendly and invited us to their villa in Portugal. (same subject)
>
> Footballers these days earn more money but they are fitter and play many more matches. (same subject)
>
> It was an expensive hotel in the centre of Stockholm, but we decided it was worth the money. (different subjects)
>
> When a subordinate clause comes before the main clause, we commonly use a comma to separate the clauses. However, we do not always do this in short sentences:
>
> If you get lost in the city centre, please don’t hesitate to text us or phone us.
>
> If you get lost just phone us.

Comment: Commas don't refer to pauses (check out a speech spectrogram if you doubt this); they refer to intonation contours, and not just one, but several. And, like intonation, speakers vary  a lot. But listening is still the key sense here. If you hear it, write it; if you don't, don't. If you can't hear the difference, practice harder.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. I agree that "pause" is not quite the right term, although I do find that pauses are sometimes loosely associated with commas. I have modified the answer slightly.